# To run a batch file present in one server to check the presence of file in another server

Tags: file, batch-file

My requirement is to check for the presence of file `file_%y%-%m%-%d%-05-00.txt` in a particular path `\\servername\e$\folder\`.

The batch file is to be placed in one server A and I have to check for the presence of `file_%y%-%m%-%d%-05-00.txt` in `\\servername\e$\folder\` in server A as well as in server B.

I tried to give the path in a variable, but it just doesnt work. I tried to give the path directly, but that doesnt work as well.
 My log file contains the entry

```
Server: servername               
File file_2013-03-25-05-00.SEC HAS been found 
File file_2013-03-25-05-00.SEC HAS NOT been found
```

The script I worte is as below:

```
set d=%date:~7,2%
set m=%date:~4,2%
set y=%date:~10,4%

ECHO Server: servername >> log.txt

ECHO .....................................

IF EXIST \\servername\e$\folder\file_%y%-%m%-%d%-05-00.txt (
GOTO file_found
) ELSE (
GOTO file_not_found)

:file_found
ECHO File file_%y%-%m%-%d%-05-00.txt HAS been found >> log.txt


:file_not_found
ECHO File file_%y%-%m%-%d%-05-00.txt >> log.txt
```

Please help me find out what the error is and what modification is needed in the above script.

Comment: What do you mean with `e$`?

Comment: its just a shared drive

Comment: Are you trying to check a remote server? Like, one not at your location? Or say one on a network? Or just one inside the same machine, but on a seperate hdd?

Comment: a remote server...not at my location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike languages like Delphi, batch simply executes statements line after line, disregarding labels like `:file_found` or `:file_not_found`. The only time the labels are used is in a `GOTO`, where execution jumps to the destination label nominated (as in `GOTO file_not_found`.

Consequently, when you execute `GOTO file_found`, it executes the `ECHO file...found` and then carries on to the next statement, which is after the `:file_not_found` label.

To correct, insert

```
goto :eof
```

on the line after the `ECHO...has been found`

Note that the special label `:eof` (it's case-insensitive) is predefined in batch to mean 'the end of the batch file'- and to use this predefinition, you **MUST** use `:EOF` - with the colon, not `eof`.

---

FOUND IT!!

Since the problem appeared obvious - flow-through, generating BOTH messages, I didn't bother copy-pasting the posted code, since ***that*** had been edited as the messages differed from the code text.

The flow-through problem was fixed but then an **ADDITIONAL** problem was noted - the file was detected despite not actually existing...

I patched the **ACTUAL** code from the comment into the original question (even now still waiting on review...).

And yes - quite correct - the file **WAS** being detected, despite being absent...[insert dramatic music]

And here's why to post **EXACTLY** the code being used (with minimum censorship mumble mumble)

The `SET` lines at the start appear to have **TRAILING SPACES**. Consequently, the variables `y`, `m` and `d` had trailing spaces and the effective statement being executed was

```
IF EXIST \\.....file_2013 03 25 -05-00.SEC (GOTO ...
```

Now I've no notion of why the parser didn't throw up on this, but I'll leave that aside.

Cure: (I had to make changes to suit my date-format and networked resources, so I'll not post **MY** code)

```
@echo off 
set "d=%date:~0,2%"
set "m=%date:~3,2%"
set "y=%date:~6,4%"
```

and that should work because any trailing spaces on those lines will be ignored.

***NOTEPAD*** is famous for causing such problems. I use [EDITPLUS](http://www.editplus.com/)

Comment: Thanks...that solved one problem. But still the script doesnt work properly. It shows "file found" for a file not present in the path. I am a novice in batch scripting, and I dont know if it is due to my wrong script or if something else is causing the problem :(

Comment: @Archie: Are you sure? Unfortunately, the report you posted does not match the code. Your **CODE** specifies `.txt` and your **REPORT** says `.SEC`; the text ** HAS NOT been found** appears in your `REPORT` but not in your `CODE`. In order to analyse what's happening, we need to see the **ACTUAL** code - with a minimum of editing - only to mask confidential information.

Comment: There's not much of a change. Here is the code:
    set d=%date:~7,2%
    set m=%date:~4,2%
    set y=%date:~10,4%
    
    ECHO Server: servername >> log.txt

    ECHO .....................................
    IF EXIST \\servername\\e$\Hyperion\essbase\bin\security_bkup\backup\file_%y%-%m%-%d%-05-00.SEC  (
    GOTO file_found
    ) ELSE (
    GOTO file_not_found)
    :file_found
    ECHO File file_%y%-%m%-%d%-05-00.SEC  HAS been found >> log.txt
    GOTO end_of_file
    :file_not_found
    ECHO File file_%y%-%m%-%d%-05-00.SEC Has not been found >> log.txt
    GOTO end_of_file
    :end_of_file

Comment: Fine - if you'd just like to accept the answer, that'll wrap everything up.